Invalid key when trying to get item list in supabase bucket
I am trying to retrieve a list of items from a Supabase Storage Bucket using Postman. My current approach is as follows:
I set up my Supabase project and enabled storage buckets.
In my API request, I include the anon key (found in the Supabase dashboard) in the Authorization header as a Bearer token.
However, when I make the request to list items in the bucket, I receive the error:
InvalidKey
Here are the specific questions I have:
Is including the anon key in the Authorization header as a Bearer token the correct way to authenticate this type of request?
If not, what is the proper way to authenticate and retrieve the list of items from a Supabase bucket?
Could this error be related to misconfigured bucket permissions, or does it solely indicate a problem with the token?
error from postman

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
